# Module Installation Dates

Tags: module, extensions

Is there a way to find out what date a particular module (or all modules) were installed? Is this stored in the database somewhere?

Trying to track an issue that exists from a few years ago, so I am trying to determine what modules were already installed before the first manifestation of the issue.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is stored anywhere in the database but you could either A) hopefully look at the version control for the site B) look at the dates the files were created / updated via a file manager / ftp